# How can I boot in "Safe Mode" with rEFIt

Tags: startup, efi, safe-mode

I would like to boot safe mode but I can't because of my rEFIt.

Holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button at startup has no effect, I just get the rEFIt menu and OSX starts to boot normally.

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question on [this page](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2934918&group_id=161917&atid=821765) appears to be the same issue. Someone responded with [a detailed solution](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2934918&group_id=161917&atid=821765#artifact_comment_3868770), which might work for you as well.